# Add a suffix and prefix to some column names in R

Tags: r, r-colnames

I have a column name Food_Q_74 in a loop that becomes Food_Q_75 Food_Q_76 etc

I need to make it look like Q_74_A1, Q_75_A1 etc

I need to delete Food_ at the beginning and add _A1 at the end. So I am NOT adding a prefix as suggested. I am not only pasting at the end.

Any real help would be appreciated.

`gsub('^Food_',' ',colnames(df$columns))`
this deletes the Food_ but I can not figure out the code to add a suffix.
Also, when I run that in R it does not change the column name. When I run it in the console it shows the deletion. ???

I thought ^ was for the start and $ for the end so I tried gsub('^Food_$ '',_A1',df$columns) but this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply pasting the interim result together with "_A1":

```
without_food <- gsub('^Food_',' ',colnames(df$columns))

with_a1 <- paste0(without_food, "_A1")
```

An alternative to `paste0` would be `str_c` from the `stringr` package.

Answer (score 0):

To add something to a string (character), use the `paste0`-function.

```
namesWithoutFood <- gsub('^Food_',' ',colnames(df$columns))
paste0(namesWithoutFood,"_A1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all within `gsub`, without using `paste`:

```r
gsub("^Food_(.*)$", "\\1_A1", colnames(df$columns))
```

The `(.*)$` here means *"Capture all characters after* **'Food_'** *until the end of the string*". The `\\1_A` in the replacement means "*Use the captured group here and stick* **'_A'** *on the end."*

Comment: That works perfectly in the console, thank you!  gsub("^Food_(.*)$", "\\1_A1", colnames(finalmydat[,138:152]))
 [1] "Q_74_A1"      "Q_75_A1"      "Q_76_A1"      "A_Q_77_1_A1" 
 [5] "A_Q_77_2_A1"  "A_Q_77_3_A1"  "A_Q_77_4_A1"  "A_Q_77_5_A1" 
 [9] "A_Q_77_6_A1"  "A_Q_77_7_A1"  "A_Q_77_8_A1"  "A_Q_77_9_A1" 
[13] "A_Q_77_10_A1" "A_Q_77_11_A1" "S_77_10_A1"                                                                                But colnames(finalmydat[,138:152]) <- gsub("^Food_(.*)$", "\\1_A1", colnames(finalmydat[,138:152]))  doesn't work when run. is my line of code incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

had

`colnames(finalmydat[,138:152])`

but needed

```
colnames(finalmydat)[138:152]
```